# How to install Kivy within Anaconda?

Tags: python, kivy, anaconda

I'm new with Python so having a bit of trouble. Also on Ubuntu. Anyway, when I install Kivy the normal way (Kivy repositories), it installs the package somewhere else on my system and not with the rest of the packages in the Anaconda3 folder. How can I install Kivy within the Anaconda3 folder so that I can use it with the rest of the packages in Anaconda?

I found a couple of Kivy packages when I searched the Anaconda packages with

```
anaconda search -t conda kivy
```

but I am not sure which one to use and if they are the same as the official Kivy packages? I guess I'm just looking for an explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using anaconda3, you could install kivy on your own virtual environment.

To install kivy on a virtual env, you have to install some necessary packages. Run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y \
python-pip \
build-essential \
git \
python \
python-dev \
ffmpeg \
libsdl2-dev \
libsdl2-image-dev \
libsdl2-mixer-dev \
libsdl2-ttf-dev \
libportmidi-dev \
libswscale-dev \
libavformat-dev \
libavcodec-dev \
zlib1g-dev
```

Creating a env for kivy in conda, run this command:

```
conda create kivyinstall
```

kivyinstall is just a name for the env.

run the below command to activate the env:

```
source activate kivyinstall
```

Now make sure Pip, Virtualenv and Setuptools are fully updated.

you can use conda install or pip install once you are in the env.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip virtualenv setuptools
```

Install Cpython version 0.23

```
pip install Cython==0.23
```

now install the stable version of kivy in your env:

```
pip install kivy
```

Some linux version throws some error when installing ffmpeg package, in place of ffmpeg you could use "libav-tools"

Answer (score 1):

conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/jiayi_anaconda kivy
use above code for python3. I have found this channel using terminal, and it solved my issue.